# ghdl floating point exception 8

Tags: vhdl, floating-point-exceptions, ghdl

I am trying to code a SRAM with 32 bit address, with a Byte lane write enable. But when I try to access (read or write) address greater than x1F, I get "Floating point exception 8" when compiling with GHDL. Here is some snippets of the code:

```
entity data_mem is

port(addr : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
   enable : in std_logic;
   rd : in std_logic;
   wr : in std_logic;
   we : in std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0);
   din : in std_logic_vector( 31 downto 0);
   -- outputs 
   dout : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
   ack : out std_logic
   );
end data_mem;

architecture structure of data_mem is

type mem_type is array (31 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal mem : mem_type := ((others => (others => '0'))); -- initialize to zero

begin

mem_write : process(addr,enable, wr, we, din)
begin
  if (enable = '1') then
    if (wr = '1') then
      if (we(0) = '1') then
        mem(to_integer(signed(addr)))(7 downto 0) <= din(7 downto 0) after 2 ns;
      end if; ...
```

So when I set the address to x0000_001F or lower in the testbench, it compiles, but not when I put x0000_0020 or greater.

Comment: A complete runnable example might be useful. I think vermaete has identified the problem, but if so, ghdl's diagnostic output could be made more useful if others can reproduce the symptom.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `signed` for the address conversion.  Quite a strange type for an address.  Because you have 32 places to store data in the memory, you only use 6 bits (2^5=32) for the address.  When keeping the `signed`, bit 5 is the sign bit.  0x1ff -> positive address: OK.  0x20 -> negative address: Error ...

I guess changing the `signed` to `unsigned` (from ieee.numeric_std) will solve the problem.

Comment: So how should it be coded so address remains 32 bits? mem(to_integer(addr)) without any signed? is there another keyword/command to use? If I don't use signed, the compiler complains: prefix is neither a function name nor can it be sliced or indexed

Comment: mem(to_integer(UNSIGNED(addr)))(7 downto 0) <= din(7 downto 0) after 2 ns;

Comment: library IEEE; use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

Comment: I made this change, but it still gave the same error. In fact, my question is why is there only 32 places to store data in the memory? The address is 32 bits, so shouldn't there be 2^32 places to store data (not 2^5)? I'm a bit new to VHDL.

Comment: There are 32 storage places for vectors of 32 bits because of the `array (31 downto 0)` part of the `mem_type`.  By the way: (0 to 31) would feel more natural then `downto`.

Comment: Ok I see. I thought the array (31 downto 0) meant the number of bits, not the number of places. Thanks.